# Fail to start Glassfish 3.1: java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-6

I just purchase a ubuntu 9.0.4 VPS (256 MB Dedicated RAM (512 MB Burstable)) from A2Hosting and try to throw a Glassfish server on it. When I try `asadmin start-domain` I got this error

```
JVM failed to start: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_22/bin/java" 
(in directory "/home/harry/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config"):
java.io.IOException: error=12, Cannot allocate memory
Command start-domain failed.
```

Here is the result of the `free` command.

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:        524288     148552     375736          0          0          0  
-/+ buffers/cache:     148552     375736  
Swap:            0          0          0
```

**EDIT**
contain of `domain.xml`

```
    <java-config debug-options="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=${JAVA_DEBUGGER_PORT}" system-classpath="" classpath-suffix="">
         <jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=192m</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-server</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/endorsed${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/lib/endorsed</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Djava.security.policy=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/server.policy</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Djava.security.auth.login.config=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/login.conf</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/keystore.jks</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/cacerts.jks</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Djava.ext.dirs=${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}/lib/ext${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.javaRoot}/jre/lib/ext${path.separator}${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/lib/ext</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-XX:NewRatio=2</jvm-options>
         <jvm-options>-Xmx512m</jvm-options>
         <!-- Port on which remote shell listens for connections.-->
         <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=${OSGI_SHELL_TELNET_PORT}</jvm-options>
         <!-- How many concurrent users can connect to this remote shell -->
         <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1</jvm-options>
         <!-- From which hosts users can connect -->
         <jvm-options>-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1</jvm-options>
         <!-- Directory being watched by fileinstall. -->
         <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=${com.sun.aas.installRoot}/modules/autostart/</jvm-options>
         <!-- Time period fileinstaller thread in ms. -->
         <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000</jvm-options>
         <!-- log level: 1 for error, 2 for warning, 3 for info and 4 for debug. -->
         <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=3</jvm-options>
         <!-- should new bundles be started or installed only?
             true => start, false => only install
         -->
         <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true</jvm-options>
         <!-- should watched bundles be started transiently or persistently -->
         <jvm-options>-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true</jvm-options>
         <!-- End of OSGi bundle configurations -->
    </java-config>
```

Comment: It contain like 400 lines of code, I have the things that related to `jvm`, please let me know if u want to see the whole things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reducing the amount in the -Xmx512m line until you get something that works. Then contact your provider and see where your limits are at.

Comment: what is `-Xmx512m` signify of, Preston?

Comment: Try to reduce down to `64m` and it still does not work. The VPS that I purchase has `256 MB Dedicated RAM (512 MB Burstable)`. Any other idea? Thank you man

Comment: Xmx is your maxiumn heap size. Xms is your initial heap size. Maybe you need to explicitly set your Xms to be 256.

Keep in mind the minimum requirements are 1 GB of RAM. However I have instances running on 512.
http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-7688/abpaj?l=en&a=view

You can also look at the old 2.1 performance tuning guide. There doesn't seem to be one for 3.0 yet.
http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4343/abeik?l=en&a=view

Comment: man minimum requirement is 1GB of ram. Did not know that. So you think the error `Cannot allocate memory` is because I dont have enough memory? I try to add `-Xms128m` to `domain.xml`, but it still give me the same error.

Comment: You're problem is definitely related the system trying to allocate more memory than it has. If you can't get it to work by adjusting the Xms, Xms options you should try increasing your available RAM to the minimum.

Comment: 1GB RAM VPS is quite expensive. So Sad :(

Comment: You will need to add more swap space.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Can you explain what you said a bit more?

Comment: @Harry, if I understand correctly you have a Linux instance with 256 Mb RAM.  The usual way to make more memory available to the individual applications is to add swap space, which combines with the physical memory to result in virtual memory.  256 Mb RAM + 512 Mb swap makes Linux provide 768 Mb.  It will be slow, but it can at least run.

Comment: Do you think you can provide me with instruction on how to do it? I would greatly appreciated it. Thank you so much